# How To Find Current Django App Name

Tags: django

I have an app. I think I know the name, instamagic, but I get **`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: App with label instamagic could not be found`**

when I try to do a migration of the database

How do I find my app's name?

My folder structure

```
instamagic
   __init__.py  (empty file)
   manage.py
   settings.py
   urls.py
   api/
   image/
   templates/
   userprofile/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added 'instamagic' to your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py?

[EDIT]

When calling south migrations, use: `manage.py schemamigration [migration_name] --auto

Comment: I have added it to INSTALLED_APPS - what should I do about the path related issue

Comment: Can you show me some example code as to where this import statement is, and the rest of your project structure?

Comment: What import statement? I was trying to call `python manage.py schemamigration --auto instamagic`

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part.

Do: python manage.py schemamigration [migration_name] --auto

Comment: That is also my entire project structure - unless you want to see inside the folders?

Comment: I don't know what my migration_name is either lol #firsttimedjangoer

Comment: I figured it out by making manage.py an executable `chmod +x manage.py` and then doing `./manage.py migrate`

Comment: Cool. South can be a little picky when you're learning it, but it's a very powerful, handy tool to have.